# How to sort "no answers" questions list by "newest"?

Tags: support, tags, search, unanswered-questions

How can I search with the "newest" and "no answers" options simultaneously?

For example, when going "No Answers" tab, I don't see a way to sort by "Newest":

> [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the search filter `[android] answers:0` and sort by Newest.

There's a bunch of other useful tips you can use; for this, click the "Advanced search tips" on the right. See also the [advanced search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

> [image: Advanced search]